# How can I fix the errors in this Apex Test Class?

Tags: apex, appexchange, app, apextestrunresult

I installed an app from Salesforce Labs into my production org and later found out that there are errors in the test class. Now these errors are preventing me from deploying a different project, so I need to fix them.

Here's the app listing on the appexchange: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000E1hf7UAB

Here's a link to the test class code: https://pastebin.pl/view/e08376d9

And here are the errors I'm seeing when I run a test:

> Class: CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest Method Name: testAccessible1
> Pass/Fail: Fail Error Message: System.QueryException: List has no rows
> for assignment to SObject Stack Trace:
> Class.CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest.getUser: line 139, column 1
> Class.CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest.testAccessible1: line 66,
> column 1
>
> Class: CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest Method Name: testAccessible2
> Pass/Fail: Fail Error Message: System.QueryException: List has no rows
> for assignment to SObject Stack Trace:
> Class.CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest.getUser: line 139, column 1
> Class.CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest.testAccessible2: line 82,
> column 1
>
> Class: CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest Method Name: testCreatable
> Pass/Fail: Fail Error Message: System.QueryException: List has no rows
> for assignment to SObject Stack Trace:
> Class.CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest.getUser: line 139, column 1
> Class.CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest.testCreatable: line 97,
> column 1
>
> Class: CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest Method Name: testUpdatable
> Pass/Fail: Fail Error Message: System.QueryException: List has no rows
> for assignment to SObject Stack Trace:
> Class.CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest.getUser: line 139, column 1
> Class.CaseStatusChangeTriggerHandlerTest.testUpdatable: line 122,
> column 1

All of these errors seem to stem from two lines of code:

Lines 66, 82, 97, 122: `User u = getUser('String');`

Line 139: `Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name=:profileName limit 1];`

I'm a beginner with Apex coding, so how can I understand and fix these errors?

Comment: That stack trace does not appear to come from a managed package class. Why do you believe the Labs product is at fault?

Comment: When I install the package into a brand new developer org I get the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means you are trying to execute a SOQL query and return a single record, but you are not actually getting any results from the query.

So in your case, line 139 is your issue. You are passing in the `profileName` parameter as a condition to retrieve and store the profile object into the `Profile p` variable. But looking at the functions that are calling `getUser()`, I'm going to guess that the profileName param you're passing is is not a valid profile name.

To resolve this, you can do one of two things:

1. Pass in a real profile name into your `getUser()` method. Profiles are one of few sobjects that use actual org data, so it needs to be one from your org or one that you create during the test setup.
2. Or, store the SOQL query results as a `List<Profile> pList` instead. This will allow you to query and store the results, even if they're empty, into a list. Then, in your test code, you can check for pList.isEmpty() as opposed to throwing an error.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I used your explanation and the first option you detailed to resolve this issue.

Comment: Not a big deal, but would love if you could mark this as the accepted answer if it worked for you!